# grep for contents AFTER pattern in delimiter (serial number)

Tags: grep

Say I have a file

```
#cat serial
SerialNumber                 : G5DBSTLAJ104949
```

I only want to know what words in print $3 appear after "SerialNumber" ,

I would much prefer that the output of that command looked like this:

```
G5DBSTLAJ104949
```

Using bash, I would like to just print out where $3 just get the word after "SerialNumber". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please update the question with your `grep` attempts and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/SerialNumber *:/{print$3}' serial
```

When a line contains "SerialNumber", it only prints the third column.

Comment: For clarity, I suggest a bit of whitespace in your awk expression: `'/SerialNumber/ {print $3}'`

Comment: awk serial '/SerialNumber *:/{print$3}'
awk: cannot open /SerialNumber *:/{print$3} (No such file or directory)

Comment: awk '/SerialNumber *:/{print$3}' serial
G5DBSTLAJ104949

Thankyu work s !

Comment: @markmeddy: Thank you = upvote / accept :-)

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep` and `PCRE` mode:

```
grep -oP '^SerialNumber\s+:\s*\K\S+' file
G5DBSTLAJ104949
```